# What is the performance cost of dirty-checking of AngularJs, including the battery on a mobile device?

Tags: performance, mobile, angularjs, web

What is the performance cost of dirty-checking of AngularJs, including the battery on a mobile device?

I wonder how important it is to limit its use to optimize performance when developing a mobile website.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Even desktops have trouble if you don't limit watchers

Comment: What kind of troubles have you seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/1600888) are some good talks about performance cost of dirty-checking.

Hope that will help you!